# Outlook archiver-like application for Windows files?

Tags: windows-10, backup, incremental-backup

Normally, I saved my working-files on SSD, but it's small (50GB) then I need move them to HDD for backup and refer later, is there any tool can do the job like Outlook-archived-feature? 
I'm using Windows10.

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (software shopping). Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Answer (score 1):

There is no native tool to do this, you could schedule a Powershell job to move the files after X amount of days.

You should also consider compressing files to take up less space:

[image: Compress Contents]